# Array Initialization Function: Passing Array as Pointer: C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to initialize arrays by passing them to an initialization function as a pointer. My program compiles with no errors, but when I run it; it prints out Character Count and stops.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void initialize(int *array, int n, int value);    

int main()
{
 char ch;
 int punctuation, whitespace, digit[10], alpha[26]; 

 punctuation = 0, whitespace = 0;

initialize(digit, sizeof(digit)/sizeof(int), 0);
initialize(alpha, sizeof(alpha)/sizeof(int), 0);

while(cin.get(ch))
{
    if(ispunct(ch))
        ++punctuation;
    else if(isspace(ch))
        ++whitespace;
    else if(isdigit(ch))
        ++digit[ch - '0'];
    else if(isalpha(ch))
    {
        ch = toupper(ch);
        ++alpha[ch - 'A'];
    }

    if(whitespace > 0)
    {
        cout << "Whitespace = " << whitespace << endl;
    }

    if(punctuation > 0)
    {
        cout << "Punctuation = " << punctuation << endl;
    }

    cout << setfill('-') << setw(17) << '-' << setfill(' ') << endl;
    cout << " Character " << " Count " << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(17) << '-' << setfill(' ') << endl;


    return 0;
 }
}

void initialize(int *array, int n, int value)
{
  int i;    

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
     value += array[i];
  }
}
```

I'm not sure that I am doing anything wrong here. Although, I am a bit confused as to how pointers work after they have been passed to another function. Can someone explain?

Thank you

Comment: In the initialize function, print the value of n.

Comment: "Stops"? Hangs? Crashes? Just exits?

Comment: It prints Character    Count then exits

Answer (score 2):

You probably want
a)

```
void initialize(int *array, int n, int value)
{
  int i;    

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
     // no: value += array[i]; but:
     array[i] = value;
  }
}
```

see also [std::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

and b) move the `return 0;` off the while-loop-body

```
    cout << " Character " << " Count " << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(17) << '-' << setfill(' ') << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

edit: regarding a)
You can use

```
std::fill(std::begin(digit), std::end(digit), 0);
std::fill(std::begin(alpha), std::end(alpha), 0);
```

instead of your initialize() function or (given the context) just

```
int punctuation, whitespace, digit[10]={0}, alpha[26]={0};
```

Comment: Oh wow, now I feel really stupid, because I didn't even notice that return 0; was inside the while loop, and the way you corrected my function is the way I had it originally. Thanks, VolkerK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in C++, why not use vectors instead?
(Working with arrays* is very C style).

```
vector<int> array(n, value);
```

n = number of integers.
value = value to place in each array cell.